# Difference between subshell and if block

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any difference between:

```
set -e;
./create-git-tag.sh || {
   echo 'Could not create git tag.'
   exit 1;
}
```

and

```
set -e;
if ! ./create-git-tag.sh; then 
    echo 'Could not create git tag.'
    exit 1;
fi
```

I am guessing that the if block does not create a subshell and therefore would exit before the if block was entered? They appear to function the same, are there any differences in behavior?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would an `if` block exit before it was entered? That makes no sense.

Comment: because the condition in the if statement would cause the script to exit if it's not a subshell?

Comment: in javascript for example -  `if (thisCallThrowsAnError()){}` then the block would never get entered..right..duh

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Why does set -e not work inside subshells with parenthesis () followed by an OR list ||?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65532)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly brackets `{ }` don't create subshells, round brackets do:

> BASH(1)
>
> (*list*)
>
> > list is executed in a subshell environment.
>
> { *list;* }
>
> > list  is simply executed in the current shell
> >     environment.

So, neither the `if` statement nor the `... || { }` form have the potential to create a subshell.

A subshell environment *may* be created if round brackets `( )` are used instead of curly brackets. The OR operator `||` would only allow this stage to be reached if the first command returned a non-zero status (*ie.* ./create-git-tag.sh failed).

If `set -e` is used, all forms exhibit the same behaviour (upon the test command failing the shell exits immediately) – but behind the scenes the round brackets will have created a subshell (which doesn't appear to be useful in this example).

If `set -e` *wasn't* used, creating a subshell with `( )` would mean that the subshell would exit, but the calling shell would continue – commands which follow would still be executed.

In all cases the echo-exit command chain (and associated subshell for round brackets) is only entered upon the test command failing. But the purpose of making conditional logic is that something might fail or it might not – this is where your wording in the question doesn't make sense:

> I am guessing that the if block does not create a subshell and therefore would exit before the if block was entered?

The if block *is* "entered", it runs the test command to determine what to do next.

Personally I find the `if` statement clearer to read and prefer to use that in scripts. Operators `&&` and `||` I might use in `if`'s place when I'm using the shell "interactively".

Comment: happen to know if  `./command.sh` is equivalent to `exec command.sh`? My guess is they are different.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that they're equivalent; in both cases the `exit` will terminate the instance of the shell running the script.

Neither version of what you have creates a subshell. To prove this, consider the following experiments:

```bsh
$ cat version1
#!/bin/bash

set -e

x=7

ls /tmp/does/not/exist &> /dev/null || {
    x=42
}

echo $x


$ ./version1
42
```

```bsh
$ cat version2
#!/bin/bash

set -e

x=7

if [ ! ls /tmp/does/not/exist &> /dev/null ]; then
    x=42
fi

echo $x

$ ./version2
42
```

If you change the `{ }` in `version1` to `()` (as in the following version), that will create a subshell.  As a result, the modification of `x` within the `( )` does not affect `x` in the calling shell:

```bsh
$ cat version3
#!/bin/bash

set -e

x=7

ls /tmp/does/not/exist 2> /dev/null || (
    x=42
)

echo $x

$ ./version3
7
```

Comment: happen to know if  `./command.sh` is equivalent to `exec command.sh`? My guess is they are different.